# 3 way Vlookup or Index unable to get working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to look up two columns to see if a team is present in the other columns.  In this case if `J2:J9` exists in `N2:N9` and `R2:R9`.
Thus far I have tried using a simple Vlookup formula like below:

```
=VLOOKUP(J4,N$2:O$40000,R$2:S$40000,1,0)
```

Though I believe vlookup is limited to one column only unfortunately.
I have also tried:

```
=INDEX(N$2:O$40000,MATCH(J4,R$2:S$40000,1),0)
```

Though this does not give me what I am wanting.  Is what I am asking possible or are you able to only see if the `Team NZ` in this case is present in `N:O` but seeing if it exists in `N:O` and `R:S` and giving it a N/A not possible?  What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

UPDATE: Ideally I want if it is present to display the Team name in the column otherwise display a #N/A similar to what Column M does except it checks if it is present in all the columns

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. been wonder this one.  I am able to to compare columns individually though that would mean 3 rows.  I really would like for neatness sake to have one.  Hmmm....

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do. If NZ is the lookup value what's the required result and why?

Comment: @barryhoudini In essence I am wanting to see if back team column J is present in columns N:O and R:S.  I want a new column that does this though the formulas I have tried thus far have yet to do this.

Comment: The reason I want this is because back, draw and lay teams are not always present and this is a filter which will allow me to easily track which teams are present in all columns

Comment: Perhaps try COUNTIF like this: `=IF(COUNTIF(N:N,J4)+COUNTIF(R:R,J4),"Present","Not present")` - change `TRUE/FALSE` results as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to check if the team in 'Back' group is present in both the other groups, you need not include columns 'O' and 'S' in your lookup.

Here's a solution that uses `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(M:M,J2,R:R,J2)
```

It'll return 1 if the team is present in both the other columns, and 0 if it's not present in either of them.

And if you prefer having a message, then you can wrap the above COUNTIFS function with CHOOSE:

```
=CHOOSE(COUNTIFS(M:M,J2,R:R,J2)+1, "Not present in both", "Present in both")
```

Here's the result:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════╦═══╦═══╦═══════╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦════════╗
║   ║     H      ║          I          ║   J    ║ K ║ L ║   M   ║ N ║ O ║ P ║ Q ║   R    ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════╬═══╬═══╬═══════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬════════╣
║ 1 ║ Solution 1 ║     Solution 2      ║ Back   ║   ║   ║ Draw  ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Lay    ║
║---║------------║---------------------║--------║---║---║-------║---║---║---║---║--------║
║ 2 ║     1      ║ Present in both     ║ Melb   ║   ║   ║ Melb  ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Melb   ║
║ 3 ║     0      ║ Not present in both ║ Aus    ║   ║   ║ Aus   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Paysan ║
║ 4 ║     1      ║ Present in both     ║ Nz     ║   ║   ║ Int   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Circi  ║
║ 5 ║     1      ║ Present in both     ║ Syd    ║   ║   ║ Syd   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Syd    ║
║ 6 ║     0      ║ Not present in both ║ Circ   ║   ║   ║ Circ  ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Nz     ║
║ 7 ║     0      ║ Not present in both ║ Oeste  ║   ║   ║ Oeste ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Gois   ║
║ 8 ║     0      ║ Not present in both ║ Gois   ║   ║   ║ Gois  ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Parana ║
║ 9 ║     0      ║ Not present in both ║ Parana ║   ║   ║ Nz    ║   ║   ║   ║   ║ Nz     ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════╩═══╩═══╩═══════╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩════════╝
```

Comment: I like this, though is there a way to display the team name if it is present and then give an #N/A.  E.g if NZ is present in the columns it displays NZ.  If not, it will display an #N/A.

Comment: @HaydenDarcy, yes. Just replace "Present in both" with the cell reference to the team name, and "Not present in both" with `NA()` in my second solution, like this `=CHOOSE(COUNTIFS(M:M,J2,R:R,J2)+1, NA(), J2)`.

Comment: @HaydenDarcy, if it has worked for you and you're entirely satisfied, please consider marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

A little unclear if you are just searching column after column to find first match to J in specified columns if exists and retrieve the adjacent value. I so, you could try nesting VLOOKUPs with IFERROR.

For example:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($J4,N:O,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP($J4,Q:R,2,FALSE))
```

You can nest further VLOOKUPs if there are additional columns to search.
If not found you will get #N/A returned.

Comment: This nearly did what I wanted.  It displays the odds beside NZ.  I am looking for NZ in the N:O and Q:R, I want it to display an NZ or if not present a #N/A

Comment: This does exactly what I want.  Haha woops.  Yeah, this is great.  I can adjust the column number as needed.  In my case: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($J8,N:O,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP("NZ",Q:R,1,FALSE))

Answer (score 0):

And yet another solution to get a `TRUE` or `FALSE` answer:

```
=IFNA(MATCH(J4,$N$2:$N$40000,0)+MATCH(J4,$R$2:$R$40000,0),0)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula as shown in the pic:

[image]

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(J2,$N$2:$N$9,0)+MATCH(J2,$R$2:$R$9,0)),"Present","Not Present")
```